# How to pass a function recursively in elisp?

Tags: function, recursion, elisp

I am currently struggling with this function that is meant to filter values.

```
(defun filter (operator val sequence)        
    (if (funcall operator val (first sequence)) 
        (filter (function operator) val (rest sequence))
        (cons (list (first sequence)) 
           (filter (function operator) val (rest sequence)))))
```

Calling this function with

```
(filter (function >) 6 '(5 6))
```

Gives

```
*** Eval error ***  Symbol's function definition is void: operator
```

This snippet works fine though.

```
(defun example (lhs rhs operator)
  (funcall operator lhs rhs))

(example 4 5 (function +))

=> 9
```

My guess is that the function forgets which function it was called with originally but I have no idea what is wrong, some pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message `Symbol's function definition is void: operator` refers to this line:

```
        (filter (function operator) val (rest sequence))
```

You're trying to access a *function* called `operator`, which doesn't exist because `operator` is just a function parameter (a normal variable). (This parameter happens to be bound to a function value, but that doesn't matter.)

This should fix it:

```
        (filter operator val (rest sequence))
```